# Greek Text (babel) and English Code Text (listings): Problem

Tags: fonts, listings, babel, greek, code

I use the babel package in order to write in greek with font "kerkis".

I want to add code in english ("courier new" font) to my latex document but I get some difficulties.

Can anybody help me, please.
Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{color}   
\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Κώδικας}

\lstset{ 
%matlab
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},  
  basicstyle=\normalsize,    % COURIER NEW?     
  commentstyle=\color{green},    % comment style
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},        
  extendedchars=true,            
  frame=single,                           
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},       % keyword style
  numbers=left,                  
  numbersep=5pt,                  
  numberstyle=\normalsize\color{black}, 
  rulecolor=\color{black},        
  stepnumber=1,                   
  stringstyle=\color{magenta},     % string style
} 

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{greek}
Ελληνικά: \textlatin{this word means greek}

\selectlanguage{english}
Now I write in english

\selectlanguage{greek}
Ελληνικά

%\selectlanguage{english}???

\begin{lstlisting}[caption = \textlatin{example1.m}]
{
% Entropy
E = 0;
for i = 1:J
    if p(i) ~= 0
        E = E + p(i)*log2(1/p(i));
    end
end
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer has solved my problem! I am new here and i didn't know that i can mark your answer as acceptable.

Comment: @GreekFreak No problem! Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to

- activate the English language
- switch to the document's monospace font (which is Courier, because you've loaded the `courier` package)

in the value passed to the `basicstyle` key, like so:

```
basicstyle=\selectlanguage{english}\ttfamily,
```

[image]

Note that, if Greek was active *before* the listing, Greek will still be active *after* the listing, because all the declarations in the value passed to that `basicstyle` are local to the listing.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Κώδικας}

\lstset{
%matlab
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},
  basicstyle=\normalsize\selectlanguage{english}\ttfamily,  % COURIER NEW?
  commentstyle=\color{green},    % comment style
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
  extendedchars=true,
  frame=single,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},       % keyword style
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=5pt,
  numberstyle=\normalsize\color{black},
  rulecolor=\color{black},
  stepnumber=1,
  stringstyle=\color{magenta},     % string style
}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{greek}
Ελληνικά: \textlatin{this word means greek}

\selectlanguage{english}
Now I write in english

\selectlanguage{greek}
Ελληνικά

%\selectlanguage{english}???

\begin{lstlisting}[caption = \textlatin{example1.m}]
{
% Entropy
E = 0;
for i = 1:J
    if p(i) ~= 0
        E = E + p(i)*log2(1/p(i));
    end
end
}
\end{lstlisting}

Ελληνικά: \textlatin{this word means greek}

\selectlanguage{english}
Now I write in english

\selectlanguage{greek}
Ελληνικά

\end{document}
```