# Code snippets are not latin characters-using babel for greek

Tags: babel, greek, code, code-snippets

I am having an issue with code snippets. I am using babel as I am writing in Greek and when I want to use latin characters I type  `\textlatin{}` . Now I need to insert code in my document and latex prints the code with Greek characters. The problem is not solved using the above command outside of the;  
    `\begin{lstlisting}
            $ sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm
    \end{lstlisting}`
which I want to print. 
What I get is this:
[image]

I am using Miktex and TeXstudio on Win7.
My preamble is this

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.8cm, right=3cm]{geometry}

%-------------code snippets
\usepackage{listings}
%-------------hyperlinks
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black, 
    filecolor=blue, 
    urlcolor=blue, 
    citecolor=black}
\urlstyle{same}

%------graphics-------
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{enumerate,enumitem}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none,url=false,isbn=false,doi=false,backend=bibtex,bibencoding=auto,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{scholar}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\normalfont}

\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{2.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}
{0pt}{2.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.3ex plus .2ex}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
.....
\end{document}
```

How can I solve this so code appears normally in latin characters?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I am sorry, I hadn't thought of that. Is it ok now?

Comment: You should add the `\begin{lstlisting}...` snippet after `\begin{document}` so that your code can be directly copied from here and compiled to demonstrate your issue, making it a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: It looks to me like this is the same (or at least similar) to [Greek Text (babel) and English Code Text (listings): Problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223151/106162), the same solution of adding `basicstyle=\normalsize\selectlanguage{english}\ttfamily,` to `\lstset` seems to do the job.  Adding `\lstset{basicstyle=\normalsize\selectlanguage{english}\ttfamily,}` just after `\usepackage{listings}` gives me english text in typewriter font - is this what you're after?

Comment: Yes, that's it thank you so much. It is the same issue. The only difference is that we don't use the same font so inserting selectlanguage{} did the job.